# How to prevent item deleting twice with rtk query?

Tags: reactjs, rtk-query

I am using RTK Query and I have problems with refreshing component after I made changes in data. I am trying to remove items from the user list setting which is working. The problem is that I need to refresh the page every time I click on a button that is called handleRemoveUserListSettings because elements displayed on that page are refreshed, but for some reason, it tries to remove it the second time.

There is my API slice with RTK-query:

```js
    import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';
    
    import { appconfig } from '../config';
    import IReorderSettingListItemRequest, {
      IUserCustomListSetting,
    } from '../shared/types';
    
    export const listActionAPI = createApi({
      reducerPath: 'listActionAPI',
      baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
        baseUrl: `${appconfig.API_URL}UserCustomListSettings`
      }),
      tagTypes: ['userList'],
      refetchOnMountOrArgChange: true,
      endpoints: (build) => ({
        fetchUserListSettings: build.query<IUserCustomListSetting[], void>({
          query: () => ({
            url: '',
          }),
          providesTags: ['userList'],
        }),
        fetchDefaultUserListSetting: build.query<IUserCustomListSetting, void>({
          query: () => ({
            url: 'default',
            method: 'GET',
          }),
        }),
        createUserListSetting: build.mutation<
          IUserCustomListSetting,
          IUserCustomListSetting
        >({
          query: (list) => ({
            url: '/create',
            method: 'POST',
            body: list,
          }),
          invalidatesTags: ['userList'],
        }),
        removeUserListSetting: build.mutation<void, string>({
          query: (id) => ({
            url: `/${id}`,
            method: 'DELETE',
            refetchOnMountOrArgChange: true,
          }),
          invalidatesTags: ['userList'],
        }),
        reorderUserListSetting: build.mutation<
          void,
          IReorderSettingListItemRequest
        >({
          query: (body) => ({
            url: 'reorder',
            method: 'POST',
            body,
          }),
          invalidatesTags: ['userList'],
        }),
        editUserListSetting: build.mutation<void, IUserCustomListSetting>({
          query: (body) => ({
            url: 'edit',
            method: 'POST',
            body,
          }),
          invalidatesTags: ['userList'],
        }),
      }),
    });
    
    export const {
      useFetchUserListSettingsQuery,
      useFetchDefaultUserListSettingQuery,
      useCreateUserListSettingMutation,
      useRemoveUserListSettingMutation,
      useReorderUserListSettingMutation,
      useEditUserListSettingMutation,
    } = listActionAPI;
```

And this is how I deleting an item inside component:

```js
    const [removeListAction] = useRemoveUserListSettingMutation();
    const handleRemoveUserListSettings = useCallback(
            (id: string) => {
              removeListAction(id);
            }, [removeListAction]);
```

This is the result after deleting:
[image]

Comment: How is "remove items from the user list" different from `handleRemoveUserListSettings`? Where is it in your code?

Comment: @sallf i meant it the same